# ZK How to sort a listbox with multiple components in a listcell

Tags: sorting, listbox, zk

In below listbox, i have listcell that contains both "Select" and "Label" component. Hence even the listheader applied sort="auto", it not actually worked. Any way

```
<listbox id="idResultListBox" checkmark="true" vflex="1"  >
                    <listhead>
                        <listheader
                            label="${ labels.result.result }" sort="auto"/>
                        <listheader
                            label="${ labels.result.resultEnteredBy }" sort="auto"/>
                        <listheader
                            label="${ labels.result.resultEnteredOn }" sort="auto"/>
                        <listheader
                            label="${ labels.result.resultAuditedBy }" sort="auto"/>
                    </listhead>
                    <listitem 
                        forEach="${attAuditResultList }"
                        value="${each }"
                        disabled="${ displayMode!='view' and each.auditedDate!=null }"
                        checkable="${ each.auditedDate==null }">
                        <listcell>
                            <select value="${ each.result }" options="${ resultTypeList }"
                                if="${ each.auditedDate==null }" visible="${ each.auditedDate==null and displayMode!='view' }"
                                 />
                            <label value="${ each.result.name }"
                                visible="${ each.auditedDate!=null or displayMode=='view' }" forward="onCreate=onCreateResultLabel()"/>
                        </listcell>
                        <listcell>
                            <activeassessor if="${ each.auditedDate==null }" value="${ each.enteredBy }"
                                 />
                            <label value="${ each.enteredBy.name }"
                                visible="${ each.auditedDate!=null }" />
                        </listcell>
                        <listcell
                            label="${ each.enteredDateAsString }" />
                        <listcell label="${ each.auditedBy.name }" />>
                    </listitem>
                </listbox>
```

Comment: Let me gues, it sorts but wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are sorting your object with `sort="auto"`.
It's normal that he doesn't sort correct because you didn't specify on what to sort.

1. `<listheader sort="auto" />` is case-insensitive.
2. `<listheader sort="auto(name)" />` is case-SENSITIVE on object.name
3. `<listheader sort="auto(LOWER(name))" />` is case-insensitive on object.name

So for your second cell if you want to sort on the `enteredBy.name` case insensitive you need to do the following :

```
<listheader label="${ labels.result.resultEnteredBy }" sort="auto(LOWER(enteredBy.name))"/>
```

Comment: I tried ty user sort="auto(enteredBy.name)", however it throws an exception like "org.zkoss.zul.listitem: no method called enteredBy for null".

Comment: possible there is a null object?

Comment: Can you recreatie it in zk fiddle and share the link?